# IBM VM Creation via Softlayer API takes longer time

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I followed the example given in the below link to create a new IBM-cloud VM.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-softlayer-go-overview/index.html

```
func main() {
    sess := session.New()
    service := services.GetVirtualGuestService(sess)

    guestTpl := datatypes.Virtual_Guest{
        Hostname: sl.String("sample"),
        Domain: sl.String("example.com"),
        MaxMemory: sl.Int(2048),
        StartCpus: sl.Int(1),
        Datacenter: &datatypes.Location{Name: sl.String("sjc01")},
        OperatingSystemReferenceCode: sl.String("UBUNTU_LATEST"),
        LocalDiskFlag: sl.Bool(true),
    }

    guest, err := service.Mask("id;domain").CreateObject(&guestTpl)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("New Virtual Guest created with ID %d\n", *guest.Id)
    fmt.Printf("Domain: %s\n", *guest.Domain)
}
```

The IBM approval mail comes after an hour , and the VM related updates are generated after that mail. 
Is there a way to reduce the time ? Or is the IBM behavior takes longer time ?

Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use python for that task and one day I've faced that I need 1 hour per 1 server to create. So there is no technical solution. IBM somehow approves server creating manually.
I would recommend raise a support ticket to IBM. Now I have average 3 minutes to create a virtual server.

Just in case try to use servers like B1_1X2X100. To insure that you use standard fast setup.

Good luck